# Slow join with 3M row table

Tags: mysql, performance

I'm doing the following query in MySQL to find lat/long for session ip addresses, but after 5 or 6 sessions that query takes several minutes to return (if ever).

The ip2loc table is 2.9M rows.

```
select sessions.ip, 
       ip2loc.region_name, ip2loc.city_name,
       ip2loc.latitude, 
       ip2loc.longitude,
       count(sessions.ip) as count 
from ip2location.ip2loc, sessions 
where INET_ATON(sessions.ip) between ip_from and ip_to 
group by ip
```

The ip2loc table has the following indexes:

```
 KEY `idx_ip_from` (`ip_from`),
 KEY `idx_ip_to` (`ip_to`),
 KEY `idx_ip_from_to` (`ip_from`,`ip_to`)
```

Is there a better way to structure this query so it doesn't take what seems like forever to run?

Comment: What does `EXPLAIN` tell you? Can you share the full table structure and sample data?

Comment: How many rows are in the sessions table? And how many distinct IPs (`select count(distinct ip) from sessions`)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem:

```
INET_ATON(sessions.ip) between ip_from and ip_to
```

which is equivalent to

```
INET_ATON(sessions.ip) >= ip_from
AND 
INET_ATON(sessions.ip) <= ip_to
```

This condition cannot use an index from `sessions` table, because `sessions.ip` is wraped in a finction call.

It can use an index from locations table - but only the first key part. It's not possible to make two range scans (`>=` and `<=`) on two different key parts. The engine can use the index on `(ip_from, ip_to)`, but will need to read half of all rows in the index (1.45M rows on average) **for each row** in the `sessions` table. The engine might even decide not to use the index at all. So you end up with a *full join* of two tables.

First optimization you can do is to shrink the number of rows from the `sessions` table, wrapping the GROUP BY query into a subquery:

```
select s.ip,
       l.region_name,
       l.city_name,
       l.latitude,
       l.longitude,
       s.count
from (
    select ip, INET_ATON(s.ip) ip_bin, count(*) as count
    from sessions
    group by ip
) s
join ip2location l on s.ip_bin between ip_from and ip_to
```

If that is still too slow, you can try to store the subquery result into an indexed temporary table:

```
create temporary table tmp_session_ips(
    ip_bin int unsigned primary key,
    ip varchar(15) not null,
    `count` int unsigned
)
    select ip, INET_ATON(s.ip) ip_bin, count(*) as count
    from sessions
    group by ip
    order by ip_bin
;

select s.ip,
       l.region_name,
       l.city_name,
       l.latitude,
       l.longitude,
       s.count
from tmp_session_ips s
join ip2location l on s.ip_bin between ip_from and ip_to
```

This way the PK (`ip_bin`) from the temporary table could be used for the join. However - That's theory. In my experience MySQL did a poor job optimizing range conditions for a join. New versions might be better now.

Comment: Yes, your second example ran in 7s (compared to several minutes for my original).  The 7s is for only 78 rows in the sessions table, so I wonder what will happen when that table reaches 1000s of entries. But, this is much much much better.

Comment: @RogerGilbrat - The number of **distinct** IPs is relevant. But even when there are a lot of them, the query should scale quite well with the growing number of IPs. At least in my theory :-)

Answer (score 0):

```
select sessions.ip, 
     ip2loc.region_name, 
     ip2loc.city_name,
     ip2loc.latitude, 
     ip2loc.longitude,
     count(sessions.ip) as count 
from ip2location.ip2loc
INNER JOIN sessions ON INET_ATON(sessions.ip) between ip2loc.ip_from and. ip2locip_to 
group by sessions.ip
```

Be sure you have also an index on table sessions column IP.

You could improve you composite index adding redundancy for the columns you need in select:

```
KEY `idx_ip_from_to` (`ip_from`,`ip_to`,region_name,  city_name, latitude, longitude )
```

In this way the query could retrieve all the info in index and not need an access to table data.

For readability you should not use old implicit join syntax based on where but use explicit join syntax based on join and ON clause.